# HTML Javascript Drag and Drop: Onmousedown or ondragstart

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, event-listener

I have some javascript which allows elements to be dragged from one div to another. I want to write some code which attaches the element to the mouse cursor during the drag, so the user can see it move places.

I have tried two things which dont quite work. Any advice on how i can tweak my code?

**Attempt one**

Change positioning of dragged element to absolute and set top,left to the mouse coordinates.
The problem with this is that it only fires on mouseup.. the element has an *ondragstart* listener. When i drag the element nothing happens; only when it gets dropped, it attaches to the mouse.

```
function drag(ev)
{


 ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
 var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

 body = document.getElementById('body');
 mouse = captureMouse(body);

body.addEventListener('mousemove',function(event)
   {
   document.getElementById(data).style.position="absolute";
   document.getElementById(data).style.top=mouse.y+"px";
   document.getElementById(data).style.left=mouse.x+"px";
   },false);


}


captureMouse = function(element)
{
var mouse = {x:100, y:100}

element.addEventListener('mousemove',function(event)
{
    var x,y;
    if(event.pageX||event.pageY)
    {
        x=event.pageX;
        y=event.pageY;
    }else{
        x=event.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft+document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        y=event.clientX+document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop
    }

    x-=element.offsetLeft;
    y-=element.offsetTop;

    mouse.x=x;
    mouse.y=y;

},false);

return mouse;
}
```

**attempt two**

This uses the same capture mouse function as above. This time, in addition to the ondragstart listener assigned to the element in the HTML, i also put an **onmousedown** listener which fires the below. The problem here is that it clashes with the ondragstart. When i give the target element an absolute position, the inline-block element next to it takes its place and is picked up by ondragstart instead.

Any suggestions? perhaps i should get rid of my ondragstart ondragover etc completely and replace with
onmousedown and onmouseup listeners?

```
function absolute(x){
body = document.getElementById('body');
mouse = captureMouse(body);
body.addEventListener('mousemove',function(event){
document.getElementById(x).style.position="absolute";
document.getElementById(x).style.top=mouse.y+"px";
document.getElementById(x).style.left=mouse.x+"px";
},false);
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are rolling your own versus using something like http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ ?

Comment: Just for the purpose of learning javascript. I recently started web development with no prior knowledge of other scripting/programming languages so thought it would be worthwhile. what do you think? just stop and start learning more jquery?

Comment: Yes you should. JQueryUI implement a lot of cross-browser functionnalities

Comment: It's very commendable to try to implement your own drag/drop functionality, but jQuery in particular is a fantastic framework and is probably your best bet if you are serious about learning web dev.  Any time you spend familiarizing yourself with it will be well spent.